# Is there anything wrong with this (c++)code? if so can anybody tell me where I went wrong?

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++ and was practicing with an exercise. I use the CodeBlocks IDE.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    double f;
    double m;
    int counter;
    counter = 0;
    for (f = 1.0, f <= 100.0, f++) { // error: expected primary-expression before ')'
        m = f / 3.28;
        cout << f << " feet is " << m << " meters!\n done";
        counter++;
        if (counter == 10) {
            cout << "\n";
            counter = 0;
        }
    }
    cin.ignore();
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Every time I put this in my IDE I get the following error:

> `error: expected primary-expression before ')' token`

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Comment: It is important to be able to reduce problematic code to a *minimal, complete example*. You could pare this down to six lines and still get the error, then look up "for loops" in your C++ tutorial.

Comment: Ahhhhhh!!!!! Incrementing a floating point index in a `for` loop.  The value `f` is incremented by 1.0.  I recommend counting the number of intervals between two floating point values.

Comment: Can you please consider accepting an answer to your question by clicking the check mark next to it? It helps a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You need to separate the clauses in your `for` statement with semicolons, not commas.
Also, it's cleaner to declare the loop variable inside the `for`:

```
for(double f=1.0; f<=100.0; f++) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your for loop statements are incorrectly separated by commas. Make them semi-colons:

```
for (f = 1.0; f <= 100.0; f++) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

`for` loops require semicolons between statements, so it should be:

```
for(f=1.0; f<=100.0; f++)
```

You're also missing a `}` after `return 0;`

Answer (score 1):

Your for statement is improper:

```
for(f=1.0, f<=100.0, f++)
```

Should be:

```
for(f = 1.0; f <= 100.0; f += 1) // for(initial value; continuation condition; increment)
```

Essentially, you need to change those commas to semicolons.